# #Discord JDA #clear/purge command, Why is my code that will clear previous messages not working as intended?

Tags: java, if-statement, discord, discord-jda

I am fairly new to the Discord JDA API and I am stuck on this problem. Whenever I run this piece of code for a "purge" command the bot only shows the error1 message. Even when I accompany the !purge with a number like "!purge 23" the bot doesn't respond. What am I doing wrong? I have been stuck at this for ages . Any help will be appreciated!

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("//s+");
    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Bot.prefix + "purge")) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            EmbedBuilder error1 = new EmbedBuilder();
            error1.setColor(Color.RED);
            error1.setTitle("❌ Specify # of messages to delete!");
            error1.setDescription("Usage: " + Bot.prefix + "purge [# of messages]");
            event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(error1.build()).queue(m -> 
            m.delete().queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        }
        
        else if(Integer.parseInt(args[1]) > 100 || Integer.parseInt(args[1]) < 1) {
            EmbedBuilder error2 = new EmbedBuilder();
            error2.setColor(Color.RED);
            error2.setTitle("❌ Only 1-100 messages can be deleted!");
            error2.setDescription("Usage: " + Bot.prefix + "clear [1-100]");
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(error2.build()).queue(m -> 
            m.delete().queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        }
        
        else if(Integer.parseInt(args[1]) < 100 && Integer.parseInt(args[1]) > 1){
            int values = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            event.getMessage().delete();
            List<Message> messages = event.getChannel().getHistory().retrievePast(values).complete();
            event.getTextChannel().deleteMessages(messages).queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("✅ " + args[1].toString() + " messages 
            deleted!").queue(m -> 
            m.delete().queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split regex is wrong. You did `"//s+"` but you should be doing `"\\s+"`.

Comment: Thank you! It's quite easy to miss these small details. I was about to quit JDA for good lmao but ty.